# Count all rows containing [Word] in [Column] in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count

I need to count and also get output of all rows in a table containing a given word in a specific column. Something like

```
ID    Name    Fave    
678   Adam    cannot bear this
355   Baloo   bear is a bear 
245   Cheeta  runs fast
```

So that I can get an output of '2' (and not '3') on counting the number of rows containing the word 'bear' in the column 'Fave', and an output of the first two rows for the tabular output/select rows.

I've tried

```
SELECT * WHERE regexp_matches(Fave, 'bear') FROM table_name
```

but I'm getting a syntax error near FROM so I'm WHERE is where the trouble is at. Any pointers/help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Fave like '%bear%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FROM` goes before the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE regexp_matches(Fave, 'bear') ;
```

You can also use `LIKE`, of course, but the issue is the order of the clauses in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where Fave ~* '\mbear\M';
```

`~*` - case-insensitive regexp matches
`'\m...\M'` - single word, so `'taddy bear'` is matching and `taddybear` is not.